# Crystal Reporting in VS2010 for Desktop Application (using winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

i am working on CRYSTAL REPORTING this time, I tried to Create it for the first time like simply adding a crystal report in VS2010 for winform but i was not able to create one, then after has some google i came to know that i need to download the CR by SAP so i downloaded it from " http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_9.exe" this link.

Then I created a data set first, load my table from database in here and after that I create the crystal report. Put some table fields in there.

After that I created a winform to watch the Report, I tried to find out Crystal Report Viewer as was suggested on different sides, but I am not able to find it in my VS2010.
Then I also download Microsot Report Viewer from this link " http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3841"

Then I use simple report viewer tool available in the toolbox and tried to use it, but not able to create one.

You can see in this video that i don't have crystal report viewer in my toolbox, i have VS2010 Professional (video link:  screencast.com/t/Ed4XGzFAn), even i've tried to reset my toolbox and tried to add it from choose items, but not working out for me.

Please someone guide me how can I create one. I'll be very thankful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you may use a web version of crystal report, you can sure that by creating a web site using vs2010 and look at toolbox --> reporting tab, if the Crystal Report viewer is present, then this version is for web